# Error in Print prime number using high order functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
val listNumbers = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
val listNumber1to100 = listNumbers.takeWhile { it < 100 }
val secNum:Unit = listNumber1to100.forEach {it}

println(listNumber1to100.asSequence().filter { it%(listNumber1to100.forEach { it })!=0 }.toList())
```

I have an error in reminder sign!
This is Error:  None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first approach, the error appears in this line:

```
it%(listNumber1to100.forEach { it })
```

A `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Int`, `Long` or `Short` is prefered right after the `%` operator, however, [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) is a function which the return type is `Unit`.

In your second approach, you have the correct expression in `isPrime(Int)`. Here are some suggestions for you:

1. `listNumber1to100` is excluding 100 in your code, if you want to include 100 in `listNumber1to100`, the lambda you pass to `takeWhile` should be changed like this:

   ```
   val listNumber1to100 = listNumbers.takeWhile { it <= 100 }
   ```
2. `listNumber1to100.asSequence()` is redundant here since `listNumber1too100` is itself a `TakeWhileSequence` which implements `Sequence`.
3. `isPrime(Int)` is a bit confusing since it is check for isComposite and it does not work for every input it takes(it works for 1 to 99 only). I will rewrite it in this way:

   ```
   fun isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = if (num <= 1) false else !(2..num/2).any { num % it == 0 }
   ```

   Since prime number must be positive and 1 is a special case(neither a prime nor composite number), it just return false if the input is smaller or equal to 1. If not, it checks if the input is divisible by a range of number from 2 to (input/2). The range ends before (input/2) is because if it is true for `num % (num/2) == 0`, it is also true for `num % 2 == 0`, vise versa. Finally, I add a `!` operator before that because a prime number should not be divisible by any of those numbers.

   Finally, you can filter a list by `isPrime(Int)` like this:

   ```
   println(listNumber1to100.filter(::isPrime).toList())
   ```

   PS. It is just for reference and there must be a better implementation than this.

To answer your question about `it`, `it` represents the only lambda parameter inside a lambda expression. It is always used for [function literal which has only one parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the expression: `listNumber1to100.forEach { it }` - is not a number, it is a `Unit` ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type)).

The compiler try to match the modulo operator to the given function signatures, e.g.: `mod(Byte)` / `mod(Int)` / `mod(Long)` - etc.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
val listNumbers = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
val listNumber1to100 = listNumbers.takeWhile { it < 100 }
fun isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = listNumber1to100.asSequence().any { num%it==0 && it!=num && it!=1  }
println(listNumber1to100.asSequence().filter { !isPrime(it)}.toList())
```

I found this solution and worked
But why can I have a non-number here in the right side of reminder

Comment: Maybe you should update your question instead of posting your solution, so that the others can see what you found easily. And, what do you mean by "in the right side of reminder"?